# How do I omit a row in a for loop?

Tags: swift

I would like to save a row number to a variable and skip that row when doing a for loop.  Would a for/where loop work?  If someone has some sample code I would sincerely appreciate it.

Comment: Add a `if` test inside your `for` loop?

Comment: Your question is to broad and too vague. When you say "row number that suggests that you're dealing with a table view or collection view? Or are you just talking about some abstract for loop? Be more specific. What are you trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 3):

You could use a `where` clause:

```
let x = 5
for i in 0..<10 where i != x {
    print(i)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use `continue` keyword for this skipping

```
let x = 5
for i in 0..<10 {
    if x == i {
      print("skipped \(i)")
      continue
    } 
   print("\(i)")
}
```